# using xdg-open in windows application ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I'm trying use ubuntu application in windows 10.

at normal ubuntu18.04 I can use xdg-open to show folder in graphical interface, but at Windows I recieve Error like that

```
marek@marek:~$ xdg-open /
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "inode/directory"
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/'
```

Is it possible to use it in windows?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: No, I just started use real linux

Comment: It's just ```start```

Comment: `xdg-open` basically requires a GUI, which of course you do not have out of the gate on WSL (just a GUI running _around_ Linux to give you that godforsaken Windows experience).

Answer (score 0):

eplorer.exe can open folder from WSL in Windows